# How can I take one child of xml file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5

I investigated this problem for hours on end.
but I couldn't find out it.
I really need you guidance for flex mobile application.

I only wanna use a xml child  (not all of them )

for example ; I only wanna this person's picture "Allen Partridge"

this is xml file :  http://adobeevangelists.com/evangelists.xml

this is my project;

```
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView"  creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" >



<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;



        protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            adres.send();
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>






<fx:Declarations>       
    <s:HTTPService id="adres" url="http://adobeevangelists.com/evangelists.xml"/>                
</fx:Declarations>



<s:Image id="picture" x="50" y="500" source="{adres.evangelist.(name == 'Allen Partridge').profileimage}" /> 




<s:List left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="500" dataProvider="{adres.lastResult.evangelists.evangelist}" labelField="name" ></s:List>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the first element of `evangelists`, you can simply do:

```
evangelistsXML.evangelist[0]
```

You can also search for a value, so if you "only want Allen Partridge's profile image", you can do this (assuming there is only one Allen Partridge):

```
evangelistsXML.evangelist.(name == 'Allen Partridge').profileimage
```